# Beautifulsoup4 Python extracting data

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the address from [this site](https://panoramafirm.pl/%C5%9Bl%C4%85skie,b%C4%99dzi%C5%84ski,b%C4%99dzin,ma%C5%82achowskiego,45/mega_bit_serwis_laptopow_i_gsm-kpazf_fpu.html), and the html look like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-address">
<div>ul. Małachowskiego 45<br />42-500 Będzin<br />woj. śląskie</div>
</div>
```

So far I use

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(firma, "lxml")
address = soup.find("div", class_="col-address")
if address:
    address_firmy = (address.text)
```

And I get: `"ul. Małachowskiego 4542-500 Będzinwoj. śląskie"`

So now two questions:

1. how to I put spaces where originally the **br** tag was?
2. how can split the string into separate fields (in csv): street, postcode, town, area?

It is probably very simple but I am totally new to programming and Python... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [56]: soup.div.get_text(separator=',', strip=True)
Out[56]: 'ul. Małachowskiego 45,42-500 Będzin,woj. śląskie'
```

- You can specify a string to be used to join the bits of text together using `separator`
- You can tell Beautiful Soup to strip whitespace from the beginning and end of each bit of text using `strip=True`